# Hybris - Adding new column in cscockpit search result

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cs-cockpit

I am customizing the cscockpit for a module Order Search. Presently it shows three fields in the Order Search Result list. This setting is configured in a CockpitGroup.xml file named Order_OrderSearchResult_CockpitGroup.xml (Location: hybris\bin\ext-channel\cscockpit\resources\cscockpit\import\config)

My customized project is at location: hybris\bin\custom
How should I make a custom file of existing CockpitGroup.xml to include my new field?
The contents of Order_OrderSearchResult_CockpitGroup.xml are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list-view unassigned-group-name="Other">
    <group name="General">
        <property qualifier="Order.creationtime" visible="true"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.code" visible="true"/>
        <property qualifier="Order.salesApplication" visible="true"/>
    </group>
</list-view>
```

I want to add a new field Order.downloadDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not asking how to add `<property qualifier="Order.downloadDate" visible="true"/>` to that xml, and are asking instead how to configure the use of your customised file.

Look at the examples in "projectdata_cscockpit_ui_components.impex" delivered with the yacceleratorcockpits template. This will form part of your Accelerator project after modulegen.

Comment: Thanks @Stretch! I just looked at your answer. I resolved using the same approach.